# GDI+ Operation invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, system.drawing

I encountered a problem while developing a .Net Core WEB API.

Sadly I am restricted to .NET Core and need to implement a Service which edits Images and sends them back.

.NET Core does not implement System.Drawing, so I used the [Windows Compatibility Pack](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/16/announcing-the-windows-compatibility-pack-for-net-core/) for .Net Core.

So far so good. I can use the Image classes I need but when testing the service, following exception occures:

[Screenshot of the Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stjx1.png)

The Code which throws this exception is following:

```
public class ImageBlurrer
{
    public static Image Blur(Image image, Rectangle rectangle, Int32 blurSize)
    {
        Bitmap blurred = (Bitmap)image;   //image.Width, image.Height);

        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(blurred))
        {
            // look at every pixel in the blur rectangle
            for (Int32 xx = rectangle.Left; xx < rectangle.Right; xx += blurSize)
            {
                for (Int32 yy = rectangle.Top; yy < rectangle.Bottom; yy += blurSize)
                {
                    Int32 avgR = 0, avgG = 0, avgB = 0;
                    Int32 blurPixelCount = 0;
                    Rectangle currentRect = new Rectangle(xx, yy, blurSize, blurSize);

                    // average the color of the red, green and blue for each pixel in the
                    // blur size while making sure you don't go outside the image bounds
                    for (Int32 x = currentRect.Left; (x < currentRect.Right && x < image.Width); x++)
                    {
                        for (Int32 y = currentRect.Top; (y < currentRect.Bottom && y < image.Height); y++)
                        {
                            Color pixel = blurred.GetPixel(x, y);

                            avgR += pixel.R;
                            avgG += pixel.G;
                            avgB += pixel.B;

                            blurPixelCount++;
                        }
                    }

                    avgR = avgR / blurPixelCount;
                    avgG = avgG / blurPixelCount;
                    avgB = avgB / blurPixelCount;

                    // now that we know the average for the blur size, set each pixel to that color
                    graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(avgR, avgG, avgB)), currentRect);
                }
            }
            graphics.Flush();
        }
        return blurred;
    }
}
```

"blurred" is an Image Object.

Does anyone know a way to solve this issue? 
Or shall I develop a full framework service instead. This is only a worst case option tho.

Comment: Internally getpixel locks the image in memory accesses the scan line, reads the appropriate amount of bits depending on the pixel format, then unlocks it. Is this just a simple example? this is not multi threaded or anything by any chance? also what pixel format is this image (id be curious).?

Comment: No there is no multi threading involved. I am going to edit my post so you can see the whole Code of the Class that is throwing the exception.

Comment: Does calling `LockBits()` cause an error? `Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);`
    `BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);`

Comment: The reason i ask is because, thats what it does internally anyway, also by accessing the scanlines you will get factors better performance

Comment: Executing your code throws exactly the same exception at ´BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);´

Comment: yeah i feared that, id be looking at your pixel format and if the image is actually corrupt or has 0 width and height, also try another image

Comment: Inspecting the Image Object in the debugger, I found that the argument: image.Palette trew an System.ArgumentException. Could that be relatet to the problem?

Comment: What pixel format is the image

Comment: When inspecting the Object again it shows that the pixel format is: "Format24bppRgb". If that is not what you meant, i am sorry my knowledge regarding image processing isn't that high by now.

Comment: Well something seems weird, this maybe just .netcore. and the compatibility pack, i'm surprised you can even do GDI in core anyway, maybe look at another image, create one in paint. failing that you might need to look at some image processing lib that supports core

Comment: Lastly, if this dosnt get answered, it might be worth while putting a bounty on it, or asking someone generously if they can bounty it for you

Comment: Probably just need to Dispose that SolidBrush